# Constructor inheritance C++, what does it offer?

Tags: c++, constructor, unique-ptr

I have this piece of code for a Tree. The nodes contain the actual data. BST is a wrapper around them by inheriting from `unique_ptr<BSTnode<Key,Data>>`. BST doesn't add any new fields to the class.

If I comment out the constructor inheritance `using unique_ptr<BSTnode<Key,Data>>::unique_ptr` my code keeps working, so what exactly does it do?

```
template <class Key, class Data>
class BST : public unique_ptr<BSTnode<Key, Data>>
{
using unique_ptr<BSTnode<Key, Data>>::unique_ptr;
BST<Key, Data>() = default;
~BST<Key, Data>() = default;
BST<Key, Data>(const BST<Key, Data> &other) = delete;
BST<Key, Data>(BST<Key, Data> &&other) = default;
BST<Key, Data> &operator=(const BST<Key, Data> &other) = delete;
BST<Key, Data> &operator=(BST<Key, Data> &&other) = default;

BST<Key, Data>(unique_ptr<BSTnode<Key, Data>> &&nodeptr) : 
unique_ptr<BSTnode<Key, Data>>(move(nodeptr)){};

BST<Key, Data> &operator=(unique_ptr<BSTnode<Key, Data>> &&nodeptr)
{       
    this->unique_ptr<BSTnode<Key, Data>>::operator=(move(nodeptr));
    return *this;
};
}
```

Testing program:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    BST<int,int> t; // default constructor
    t.add(1,1);
    BST<int,int> t2 = move(t); // move constructor
    // BST<int,int> t3 = t2; // copy constructor is deleted
    BST<int,int> t4; // default constructor
    t4 = move(t2); // move operator
    // t4 = t3; // copy operator=deleted !

    BST<int,int> nodeptr = std::make_unique<BSTnode<int,int>>(); // + 
    // + node move constructor
    t4 = move(nodeptr); // node move operator=
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One question per question please

Comment: Ok, that isn't considered spamming?

Comment: I do not think so, but you should create [mcve] - you have significant amount of irrelevant code.

Comment: All the remaining code is necessary for the statements of the testing program. It is even so minimal that it won't compile if you use just that. I don't see how I can make it any shorter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of constructor inheritance is, you want to say "all the constructors are just like in the super-class" using **one source code line**, and not one line per constructor.

So if you want to use this feature, you should **remove** all your constructor definitions:

```
BST<Key, Data>() = default;
~BST<Key, Data>() = default;
BST<Key, Data>(const BST<Key, Data> &other) = delete;
BST<Key, Data>(BST<Key, Data> &&other) = default;
BST<Key, Data> &operator=(const BST<Key, Data> &other) = delete;
BST<Key, Data> &operator=(BST<Key, Data> &&other) = default;
BST<Key, Data>(unique_ptr<BSTnode<Key, Data>> &&nodeptr) : 
unique_ptr<BSTnode<Key, Data>>(move(nodeptr)){};
```

and **replace** them by one line of code:

```
using unique_ptr<BSTnode<Key, Data>>::unique_ptr;
```

(Note: if you define additional constructors to the ones inherited, you need to define the default constructor explicitly)

Comment: If you had to give a signature for any of the inherited constructors, what would that look like?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't exhasted the ways of constructing a `std::unique_ptr<BSTnode<Key, Data>>`

```
BST<int,int> t5{ new BSTnode<int,int> }; // from raw pointer
BST<int,int> t6{ nullptr }; // from nullptr
```

But if you exhaustively add everything that a `using` would add, then it becomes superfluous